# Any free alternatives to missing sync on OS X (for Palm OS HotSync)?

Tags: macos, mac, palm

I have a device (Alphasmart Dana) that requires Palm OS HotSync manager, but it's no longer supported by 10.6.

Comment: iSync doesn't work?

Comment: It's an old device (Alphasmar Dana, 2005) that requires HotSync for Palm OS; but as of Mac OS 10.6, HotSynch is not compatible with mac

Comment: Writing software to talk to all the different devices, including testing, must be a major pain in the ass, so it's unlikely someone did it for free.

Comment: Hm, ok. I guess I'll have to do with the "virtual keyboard feature" (it connects as a keyboard, you open a blank document, press "send", and it types up what you wrote)... downside is it's plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that I have been able to come arcorss, besides [confirming](http://kb.hpwebos.com/wps/portal/kb/common/article/33219_en.html) your issue, is the software mentioned in that KB articled linked there.  **[The Missing Sync](http://www.markspace.com/products/palm/palm-sync-software.html)**, no, it is not free, however, it is designed to sync up the Palm OS to the Macintosh computer, even to version 10.6.

iSync, built into Mac, unfortunately will not do it without the Palm Desktop, and the latest versions of both the desktop and hotsync manager just are not going to work with 10.6.

Wish i could give you better news, but that is all I have been able to find thus far.

Comment: Yeah, I've not found anything else either :S.

Answer (score 0):

try [syncmate](http://mac.eltima.com/sync-mac.html) - it is apparently a free alternative to the missing sync. Unfortunately, I don't have that phone or OSX to try it out on, but it's worth a shot, I think

Comment: Can you expand your answer please? How exactly does it solve the problem, etc.